# StringVar() as abc='123456779'

Tags: python, tkinter

This REALLY shouldn't be that difficult. Unless I am overlooking something. I've been going in circles trying to get tkinter to accept a Entry(root) entry as a string. If I define the variable as

> abc='123456789'

the code runs.

If I try to make abc =label_text which is the result of a function I get the error;

> StringVar object is not iterable.

How do I get the function object to act like a defined string?

Thanks!

```
#odd series
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
odd=0
n=2
abc='1234567'
def show_text():
    label_text.set( entry_text.get())
entry_text = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=12, textvariable=entry_text)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root,text="Run add", command=show_text)
button.pack()


label_text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

#Add odd
for i,x in enumerate(label_text):
    if i % n == 0:
        odd=odd+int(x)

label2=tk.StringVar()       
label2=tk.Label(root,text=odd)
label2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

label_text is a tk.StringVar object. You need to call .get() to get the string it represents.

```
#Add odd
for i,x in enumerate(label_text.get()):
    if i % n == 0:
        odd=odd+int(x)
```

The label keeps the text = because your for loop is only evaluated once when the entry is empty, so its length is 0.

If you want the second label to update with this length, you have a different problem. `odd` is a python variable, not a tkinter Variable object, which has bindings to notify listeners like the tkinter Label. You have a few options for that. You could bind an event to the entry, use the entry's validation feature (somewhat more complicated), or simply update when the button is clicked as shown below.

```
odd = tk.IntVar(root)

#Add odd
for i,x in enumerate(label_text.get()):
    if i % n == 0:
        odd.set(odd.get()+int(x))

label2=tk.Label(root, textvariable=odd)
label2.pack()
```

This will tie the value of "odd" to the display of "label2", but your for loop still only runs once, before initialization. To fix this, you need to re-evaluate any time the button is pressed:

```
def calc_length():
    for i,x in enumerate(label_text.get()):
        if i % n == 0:
            odd.set(odd.get()+int(x))

def show_text():
    label_text.set(entry_text.get())
    calc_length()



entry_text = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=12, textvariable=entry_text)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root,text="Run add", command=show_text)
button.pack()


label_text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

odd = tk.IntVar(root)
```

Comment: Daniel B.. I changed to enumerate(label_text.get()), but odd shows 0 and stays 0 when I press the button.

Comment: I've updated my response to address that issue, though it really should be a separate question.

Comment: I am completely lost with tkinter. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: If the answer was satisfactory, could you please accept it? If not what are you still having issues with?